# Is all of this because a user was removed?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-users

[image: Serial Downvoting?]

I noticed today that several of my older questions had suddenly come up with -2 rep. I also had one that indicated that the user was removed.
 According to the info for that (bolding is mine):

> All the reputation changes from a single user's deletion are **rolled into a single event** in the reputation page labelled "User was removed".

Since this seems to be more than one event I was wondering if a.) the "user removed" process was broken or 2.) someone had performed a little serial down-voting?

Comment: I see 4 downvotes. That's not `User was removed`. These are separate things, even if they appear close to each other in the timeline.

Comment: The removed user actually upvoted one of your answers, or two of your questions.

Comment: Cool. That means the upvotes would be removed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like a user was removed.

And **possibly** another user went on a downvote spree.

Comment: I'm sure the serial voting doohickey will likely take care of it then. I was just curious if the "user removed" function was broken.