# For "User was removed" event, why are editing reputation points rolled back? It can be sort of unfair?

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-users

I got this message today:

[image]

So I tapped to learn more and then read the description of the event on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed). The most important thing was this:

> As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you
>   gained or lost from them was undone.

Now as evident from the reputation points change, it must have been some editing events. I then started digging on meta and found [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265611/is-all-of-this-because-a-user-was-removed), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted) very helpful in understanding the event. But what I don't understand is since I got the reputation earned from editing their questions/answers which most likely were approved by other users, why do I have to suffer if that user violated the network's policies? Okay, votes I understand, because a malicious user might have been casting votes without even thinking about it. But why do editing events have to be covered in the same blanket?

I am just curious. Isn't it rather unfair that you lose the reputation points which you worked for (which you did not gain just because some user just randomly tapped upvote) just because that user stepped out of line? In my case, it is only four, but in someone else's case it could possibly be a lot higher. Why do editing-related reputation points have to be rolled back as well? What is the rationale behind it? Also, does it affect my progress on the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) badge? (I checked the progress, and I don't think it did affect my progress).

Comment: You actually lose reputation for suggested edits where the user removed was the final approver of the edit, because their user ID gets recorded on the "vote" which gives you the reputation. It doesn't revert all reputation you've gained from suggested edits on the users' posts. I'm not sure how difficult it would be to simply ignore that vote type when deleting all the votes on user deletion, or even just always transferring that vote type to the Community user on deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @animuson. But I assume you are somewhat agreeing with the premise that it is unfair to the editor right? Regardless to who approved the edit suggestion? Also, can you please confirm if it affects my progress on editing badges?

Comment: This doesn't affect badges. The edit and the post still exist. It's only the vote that's being deleted. -- As far as it being unfair, *not* deleting the votes would make this exploitable. Users could create sock-puppets which create a single post, they could suggest an unlimited number of edits on it and have the sock just keep insta-approving them, and then the reputation would never be erased upon deletion of the sock. Deleting the votes means all that ill-gotten reputation gets erased correctly. It's a tough compromise.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks @animuson. Could you please post these comments as answer?

Comment: @NSNoob You can always add the answer yourself, this is meta to no rep here anyway. Or add it as a community wiki if you prefer.

Comment: @DavidG not that it really matters but badges are still awarded.....

Comment: @animuson: could the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed) be updated with your explanation, or something similar to it? It seems like an appropriate place for that info.

Comment: When I was more active and I started to face user removals I tended to ignore low rep user questions as they often deleted their accounts so any work spent was lost.

Comment: @LeosLiterak for a user to delete their account they have to contact Stack Exchange. Their account can be deleted by a moderator, community manager or staff member for any number of reasons but the most common being fraudulent voting. The account can also be deleted after a period of inactivity, but IIRC rep gained from those users is not lost when their account is deleted. I could be wrong on that last part though.

Comment: @TinyGiant Reputation lost is a thing to deal with - I know that my answers were helpful. But when I edit bad formatted question then its removal voids my work. I hate to do useless/meaningless work.

Comment: @leos That's just part of the game I guess.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As Answered by [@animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) and I quote:

> **You actually lose reputation for suggested edits where the user removed was the final approver of the edit**, because their user ID
>   gets recorded on the "vote" which gives you the reputation. It doesn't
>   revert all reputation you've gained from suggested edits on the users'
>   posts.
>
> **This doesn't affect badges**. The edit and the post still exist. It's only the vote that's being deleted. -- As far as it being unfair,
>   not deleting the votes would make this exploitable. Users could create
>   sock-puppets which create a single post, they could suggest an
>   unlimited number of edits on it and have the sock just keep
>   insta-approving them, and then the reputation would never be erased
>   upon deletion of the sock. Deleting the votes means all that
>   ill-gotten reputation gets erased correctly. It's a tough compromise.