# Edited posts count decreased- Under what scenarios can this occur?

Tags: discussion, support, edits, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

On Friday, I distinctly remember my edited posts count was on 61. But today when I opened SO, it has somehow decreased to 58.

[image: badge progress]

[image: impact]

From [This Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311251/for-user-was-removed-event-why-are-editing-reputation-points-rolled-back-it), it is my understanding that even deleting users does not affect badge progress on editing badges. [This help center post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) does not help regarding this aspect. Also, I did not receive any reputation change if the user/post were deleted:

[image: Sample of last few days]

Has it happened because maybe some posts were deleted? What are the scenarios in which a user may lose progress on editing badges?

Comment: Edit rollbacks?

Comment: @Steve Do rollbacks result in loss of editing badge progress? Is there any reference to it? If yes could you please share it and post it as answer then?

Comment: I'm not sure and don't have any evidence, just throwing it out there. It seems reasonable though.

Comment: Looking at the questions in your screenshot, there doesn't appear to a rollback. Are you *sure* you were at 61 on Friday?

Comment: I am positive Steve. It was 61. The 3 edits you see in the Screenshot are the ones that made it to 61. But I wouldn't completely discount the possibility that I might be mistaken. Accessing Cached copies of the web page wouldn't be help either as to view those stats, Login is required.

Comment: In that case I'm not sure, someone with more knowledge of how badges are calculated will have to answer.

Comment: [Edits on deleted posts do not count](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732).

Comment: @approxiblue Thanks mate  I suppose that must have been it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the MSE badge description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions#188732), the criteria for edits counting towards Strunk & White are:

> 1. **Edits on deleted posts do not count**
> 2. Edits to your own posts do not count
> 3. Edits to community wiki posts do count
> 4. Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> 5. Tag wiki edits do count
> 6. Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved
> 7. Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

This [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) also states that deleted posts don't count.

*So, it appears that badge progress was decreased by three because three posts were deleted.*

Comment: I think this is likely to happen if you edit those horrible 1 rep user posts.

Comment: I think so @TomášZato . I don't usually bother about rep of the people whose posts I edit.