# -1 For User Removed

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-users

I fully understand what the message means and why it happened. My curiosity is about the -1. This means the removed person had caused me a gain of 1 rep point which has now been removed. How does a user give me a total of 1 rep?

Is this just some combination of question up votes and answer down votes for a net of 1 (say +5 -2 -2) or some other random combination of up and down votes that netted 1?

Or am I missing some other obvious way for a user to give me a rep gain of just 1?

Just curious.

Comment: Or you had 199 and a +x from an upvote hit the rep cap, hence just +1.

Comment: When you are reputation capped, downvote an answer, then receive another upvote on one of your posts, you get a +1 reputation change. If the voter was subsequently deleted, you see a -1 event. Or the user upvoted one of your questions and downvoted 2 other posts, giving you a net change of +5 -2 -2 == +1. Or another combination. It doesn't really matter, does it?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I would be equally curious to know, even if it doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things. Sorry rmaddy is more curious than you are.

Comment: @Tom I went through OP's reputation history and it's not the case of rep cap :)

Comment: @BoltClock: sure, but as we both know, the system can't let us know more than the net change, because we wouldn't want to accidentally reveal who the voter was. To do otherwise would break the anonymity of voting on this site. We'll just have to remain curious.

Comment: @xenteros: you can't know that. We can't see downvotes in the reputation history. The OP has been reputation capped in the past, a downvote and subsequent +1 upvote would be hidden from us (we just see a 0 point upvote).

Comment: @xenteros: and the OP can't see the +1 upvote anymore *either*; the vote has been undone as if never cast; another, later upvote (if one exists for that day) will now have been promoted to +1.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I wish I knew it before browsing his reputation history for 14 months :D

Comment: Why is the reputation removed it a user is removed? From my understanding, an upvote was "earned" at some point in time and shouldn't go away with the user.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Just listing some of the likely possible combinations that could result in a net +1 rep change would have been enough to satisfy my curiosity - I don't know about rmaddy, though. I don't imagine they care precisely which one of those combinations this instance resulted from.

Comment: @Matt because if a user is removed, it means (among other things) we don't trust their judgement on when to up- or down- vote.

Comment: @Matt See also this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it

Comment: @poke and Martin - thanks for the clarification. I can understand it if the user violates the terms of service, but if the account was removed due to inactivity or because the user himself has requested it, the reputation and upvotes could stay in my opinion.

Comment: @Matt Please keep these comments on topic to this question. If you wish to understand why reputation is removed along with a user, please post a comment to one of those related questions. Thanks.

Comment: @BoltClock More power to curiosity. I just found it odd to lose 1 point. I'm used to losing some multiple of 10 when a user is deleted. Just simple curiosity. I know we can't know the exact reason. I did forget about rep caps being a possible cause. So in addition to the reasons I listed in my question, I think that covers it.

Comment: According to the SE meta, if some user requests to have their account deleted, their votes are rolled back... even if they were a solid user with no suspicious voting habits. How this makes sense, nobody knows.

Comment: @Lundin Not saying that I agree/disagree with the following idea, but perhaps it's comparatively like a person requesting privacy on an issue: by requesting to have their account deleted, it's effectively a request to remove their footprint on the site.

Comment: @OhBeWise Except SO greedily decides to keep all of their posts in the form of community wiki, so the "remove footprint" argument isn't even there. Basically SO recognizes that their technical contribution was fine but that their voting habits were suspicious (even though they really weren't). As I said, nobody knows how this makes any sense.

Comment: @Lundin Can we please keep comments on topic to this question, thanks. Keep comments related to the "-1" part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different reputation-affecting actions which can be reversed when a user is deleted.

#### Reputation events listed as *user was removed*

- User who upvoted your answer is removed (-10)
- User who upvoted your question is removed (-5)
- User who was the final approver of a suggested edit is removed (-2) <sup>[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311251/for-user-was-removed-event-why-are-editing-reputation-points-rolled-back-it/311413#311413),[2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249804/351462),[3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/351462)</sup>
- User who downvoted your question/answer is removed (+2)

**Looking at this, the most likely answer is that your guess was correct:**

- One question upvote removed (-5) and two question downvotes removed (+4)

---

As [Martijn Pieters points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355806/1-for-user-removed/355865#comment509007_355806), another possibility is due to the **daily reputation cap.**

> When you are reputation capped, downvote an answer, then receive another upvote on one of your posts, you get a +1 reputation change. If the voter was subsequently deleted, you see a -1 event.

---

Finally, if the deleted user's posts were also removed, there are a few other possibilities, but these ones seem ***fairly unlikely***.

(The [list of reputation events](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/351462) doesn't specify whether these would be listed as *user was removed*)

- An answer you accepted was deleted (-2)
- An answer you downvoted was deleted (+1)

Comment: If I accept an answer and then that user is later deleted, can that accepted answer really be deleted too? I haven't posted many questions so I have no idea if that is possible.

Comment: @rmaddy In most scenarios, I doubt that an accepted answer would be deleted. While it is *possible* for a user or moderator to manually delete an answer, this usually only happens to very low quality or plagiarized posts. I was simply pointing out it might *technically* be a possibility.