# How is reputation count history evaluated?

Tags: discussion, reputation-history, daily-reputation-limit

Due to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355806/4723795) question I went through rmaddy's reputation history and I've found something strange:

[image]

As far as I know, accepted answers don't count for the daily reputation limit. As we have three accepted answers here, it results in 45 reputation. The upvotes sum up to 200 as permitted. Look, one upvote even resulted in +0 due to the rep-cap.

Where is the remaining +15? Is it accepted answer to the question which was deleted? I can already see deleted posts, so I should probably see it.

What is the explanation of this?

Comment: There was an accepted answer on a question that was deleted, yes. However, users' deleted posts don't appear in their post activity/reputation history for other users.